# Can @supports in CSS be used to distinguish between Chrome and Android?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, screen-resolution

I've successfully used CSS @supports to distinguish between iOS and Android on mobile devices with:  @supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch)

I would like to distinguish between Android and Chrome in a similar way, in order to distinguish an Android high resolution device in landscape orientation from a desktop layout with the Chrome browser.

(Note: I'm using orientation in the @media query to successfully tell if a device is portrait or landscape. However I still have the problem of a high res device in landscape mode using the desktop layout, and it does not fit on the screen. If I can distinguish, I can use a different layout.)

Comment: Android is an OS.  Chrome is a browser, which sometimes runs on Android.  You can't distinguish between them, because they aren't the same category of thing.  I think you're asking something else, but your post isn't clear enough to answer.

Comment: I recommend you to read this: https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-design/ If your design doesn't fit because of device-type it means your responsivessness isn't working for you. You can target ```min-width``` and ```max-width``` instead of device types.